# How can I make the icon of a folder to be a given .icns file?

Tags: macos, icon

I have a `.icns` file.
I want to make the icon of folder to be this `.icns`.

How can I make that?

---

### EDIT

The `.icns` file that I use does not have the `.icns` file as its icon.

I have tried to copy the `.icns` file in `Preview` and paste it to the icon, but it copies the `1024x1024` image.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. "Get Info" of the folder you want the icon to be replaced,
2. using Finder, drag and drop the *.icns file to the current **top**, i.e. smaller icon of the folder in the "Get Info" window.

[image: example]

Comment: Or open the "Get Info" inspector (CMD + I) of the folder and the one of the icon. Click the icon copy it (CMD + C) and click the folder icon then paste the clipboard content (CMD + V). PS: You may paste any kind of image althought better to use a square image of at least 1024px and a format that includes transparency such as PNG.

Comment: @llange Your method works only if the `.icns` file the `.icns` file as its icon, which is not the case for my file :(

Comment: @piobyz Great, it works like a charm!

Comment: I must have poorly explained myself, and I'm sorry for that (my apologies). If you have an "icns" file (icon) you may use the inspector on both files and copy paste (because some times drag and drop isn't convenient). If instead you have an other type of image copy the image (e.g.) from Preview.app : select all (CMD + A) copy (CMD + C) and paste the clipboard content to the folder inspector (the PS part of my previous comment).

Comment: Did not work for me in Mojave.

Answer (score 2):

Open the `.png` file in Preview (or convert image to png) or open `.icns` in Preview

Press <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select the entire image

Press <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy the selection

<kbd>Control</kbd>+Click on the file/folder you would like to change and "Get information"

Click the icon (so there is a blue frame around it)

Press <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste the image into that.

*Sometimes you can go straight from the Get Info window of the `.icns` and copy the image icon there into the Get Info of the item you want to change. This works for most Apps except Finder.

Comment: I think it does not copy the `.icns` but the `1024x1024` image...

Comment: Have you tried it because I have done what you are talking about multiple times with success each time. Mac OS is kick ass and so is Preview. Open the .icns in preview and copy it. It'll work

Comment: I checked: it does not copy the `.icns`, it copies the `1024x1024` image.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem myself and the only solution I found was to use Cocoa:
    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] setIcon:image forFile:filePath options:0];

I've written a simple app that just asks for an icon, then a file or folder on which to apply that icon.  You can download it here:
http://d.pr/f/2qRK/1k0UHTJ6

Comment: Have you checked @piobyz's answer?

Comment: Well @piobyz's answer is certainly easier, thank.  I just take any opportunity to write an app :)

Comment: Note: As of this writing, the link in the answer is dead.

Comment: Link is alive again.

Comment: This worked for me where the accepted answer didn't. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I solved this problem:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v1K63UhKaOA

I created an empty app with the .icns inside and then copy/paste from the info of the app to the info of the folder.

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.